# Accessing Bottle webserver VM form Host

Tags: web-server, virtual-machines, virtualbox, host

I have an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM running and Bottle webserver on `http://0.0.0.0:8080`. How can I access this on my host (OSX)?

I want to do this because accessing the web server using FireFox on the VM is incredibly slow. I've tried to change my network settings to `host-only` and bridge adapter but so far no success. My goal is to access/interact with the Bottle web server on my Host (OSX) machine in hopes it is much more faster to use.

With bridge adapter, it seems like I should have full access from my Host to the VM's web server.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access anything from the host, you need to:

1. Set network adapter to "Bridge"
2. Make sure both the vm and the host are on the same network.

**Trouble shooting**

Step 2 can sometimes lead to problems, so here are some things to test:

1. Ping the vm from the host or viceversa to see if they can *see* each other.
2. If the network configuration on the vm is done by you, double check the netmask and the ip/gateway you are giving it.
3. If they can *see* each other, then it's probably a missconfiguration in the application or the firewall.

I know for a fact that, when using kvm, by default it makes it impossible (without further configurations) for the host to communicate in any way with the vms, even if set to bridge. I've used vmware and I didn't face this problem, so you most likely have a missconfiguration somewhere.